# Skip line from console if equal than line before, adding count (in realtime)

Tags: bash, uniq, duplicate

Using uniq it is possible to filter out sequential duplicate lines.

```
while (true) do echo 1; echo 2; echo 2; echo 1; sleep 1; done | uniq
```

becomes:

```
1
2
1
```

Is there a way to have duplicated sequential lines removed, while adding the number of repetitions? E.g. in the example above

```
1
2 (2)
1
```

And if a new "1" line arrives, the above should become:

```
1
2 (2)
1 (2)
```

This is not for a file but for a stream (such as tail -f), where new lines are being added in real time.

Comment: This would mean that you were no longer removing the duplicates, but instead appending an occurrence count to them. Yes?

Comment: There's `uniq -c`, but of course the output format is different and it doesn't keep a global count, just looks at the latest repeating line

Comment: @ilkkachu unless sorted, but maybe OP doesn't want that.

Comment: Welcome, do you care about the order?

Comment: wait, I guess you didn't want a global count anyway, if you meant the last output would correspond to an input with one `1` at the front, then two `2`s, then two `1`s again (for a total of three `1`s). If so, `uniq -c` is basically your thing. Unless you want the last output line to update for each new repetition.

Comment: Whereas the uniq -c behaviour is good, it adds a delay, and only prints the output once it has finished repeating, or after a certain time. I would like something like it but in realtime.

Comment: You realise that `while (true) do echo 1; echo 2; echo 2; echo 1; break; done | uniq` isn't a loop at all, but is simply `{ echo 1; echo 2; echo 2; echo 1; } | uniq`? And as such it bears little relationship to an infinite source such as `tail -f`

Comment: @roaima I was just trying to simulate a stream of lines, as a minimal sample that could be tested in stackexchange.

Answer (score 2):

You're no longer removing duplicates, but instead you are counting them.

```
awk '{ if (h[$0]++) { s=" (" h[$0] ")" } else { s="" }; printf "%s%s\n", $0, s }'
```

The array `h[]` keeps track of the inputs (the current line is `$0`). If the value is greater than 1 it's printed along with the current line.

The unique set of lines is held in memory, so if you have a large data set with relatively few duplicate lines you will end up holding most of that data set in RAM (or at best, in swap). Be aware of this as you build out your solution.

For an input of lines `1`, `2`, `2`, `1`, `3` you will get this output:

```
1
2
2 (2)
1 (2)
3
```

If the input stream was finite (not the case with either your example or the suggested `tail -f`) then we could collect all the values and output them with their counts. But it isn't, so we can't.

Comment: Thanks for your input. However, this solution a) still shows duplicate lines but with a new counter, and b) shows as duplicates lines that are not immediately on top of each other. The output I'm getting with the above example is:

while (true) do echo 1; echo 2; echo 2; echo 1; echo 1; break; done | awk '{ if (h[$0]++) { s=" (" h[$0] ")" } else { s="" }; printf "%s%s\n", $0, s }'

1
2
2 (2)
1 (2)
1 (3)

Comment: @JoseGómez that's exactly right, yes. If you have a different intention to that which I've understood, please [edit your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/687866/edit) to make it clearer.

Comment: @roaima the third block in my question shows the expected output. I.e. no duplicate lines, which are shown as soon as they are printed, and a number is added to them in realtime if there are additional lines coming.